# Declare array/hashmap in gradle.properties file

Tags: arrays, groovy, properties, gradle

I'm trying to define an array in the gradle.properties file. When, for example, I do the next in some gradle script:

```
project.ext.mygroup = [
  myelement1: "myvalue1",
  myelement2: "myvalue2"
]
project.mygroup.put("myelement3", "myvalue3"); // As internally it works like a hashmap
```

and then I list the properties, I get:

```
mygroup: {myelement1=myvalue1, myelement2=myvalue2, myelement3=myvalue3}
```

So, if I try setting a property with the same form in the gradle.properties file:

```
mytestgroup={myelement1=myvalue1, myelement2=myvalue2}
```

And then in the gradle script I try to access this property:

```
project.mytestgroup.put("myelement3", "myvalue3");
```

I get the next error:

```
No signature of method: java.lang.String.put() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [myelement3, myvalue3]
```

This is because the property "mytestgroup" is being taken as a string instead of an array.

Does any one know what is the correct syntax to declare an array in the gradle.properties file?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't set a list or map value in `gradle.properties`, as this is a plain Java properties file where all values are strings.

Answer (score 10):

The notation `{myelement1=myvalue1, myelement2=myvalue2, myelement3=myvalue3}` is simply a string representation of the object as the result of calling `Map.toString()`. It is not syntactically correct Groovy.

Your first example is the correct way to define a `Map`.

```
def myMap = [ key : 'value' ]
```

Defining an array is similar.

```
def myArray = [ 'val1', 'val2', 'val3' ]
```

Comment: Thanks Mark! I know that's the correct way to define array/hashmap in groovy, but I'm asking about the gradle.properties file which (according to the Peter's answer) is not groovy but a java properties file.

Comment: Sorry about that, I suppose I didn't completely read your question. Peter is correct, values in properties files can only be strings.

Answer (score 3):

Set the property to JSON string

```
myHash = {"first": "Franklin", "last": "Yu"}
myArray = [2, 3, 5]
```

and parse it in build script with [JsonSlurper](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html):

```
def slurper = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper()
slurper.parseText(hash) // => a hashmap
slurper.parseText(array) // => an array
```

Answer (score 1):

The JsonSlurper way is good, but I wanted a cleaner way to define both a simple string or an array as a property. I solved it by declaring the property as:

```
mygroup=myvalue1
```

or:

```
mygroup=myvalue1,myvalue2,myvalue3
```

Then inside Gradle retrieve the property with:

```
Properties props = new Properties()
props.load(new FileInputStream(file('myproject.properties')))
props.getProperty('mygroup').split(",")
```

And you will get an array of String. Be careful with space characters around the commas.