# Add abiFilters to gradle properties

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I want to add ndk.abiFilters property in gradle.properties file. Now I've this property inside build.gradle.
Here is part of my build.gradle

```
buildTypes {
  debug { 
     ndk {
       abiFilters "x86", "armeabi-v7a", "armeabi"
       //abiFilters ABI_FILTERS
     }
   }
}
```

Here's part of my gradle.properties file

```
ABI_FILTERS = "x86", "armeabi-v7a", "armeabi"
```

Problem is that String from gradle.properties is not correctly converted for use with abiFilters. I tried many variants but with no luck. What is the correct way how to do this correctly? Thank you for help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26538489/794088

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In gradle.properties you can have for example:

```
ABI_FILTERS=armeabi-v7a;x86 //delimiter can be anything (change below)
```

Then in build.gradle there is (for example in debug buildType section):

```
ndk {
  abiFilters = []
  abiFilters.addAll(ABI_FILTERS.split(';').collect{it as String})
}
```

Now each developer can choose independetly abi for his current testing device (gradle.properties is in .gitignore).

Thanks Igor Ganapolsky for starting hint.

Comment: Hello @Warlock after adding ndk still my application not showing  armeabi-v7a lib.so files while analyzing application can you help me thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16):

Following works with Gradle 2.3:

```
abiFilters 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
```

Answer (score 4):

gradle.properties file

```
ABI_FILTERS = ["armeabi", "x86"]
```

build.gradle file

```
ndk {
  abiFilters = []
  abiFilters.addAll(ABI_FILTERS)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
flavorDimensions "abi"
    productFlavors {
        arm7 {
            dimension "abi"
            ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'
        }
        x86 {
            dimension "abi"
            ndk.abiFilters 'x86'
        }
    }
```

You can see an example of this setting in the Google samples for NDK: https://github.com/android/ndk-samples/blob/8132651aba8db36b14e0d0461c7cb46d3778f99c/other-builds/ndkbuild/hello-neon/app/build.gradle

Comment: They have removed the setting from the example. Why have they removed it?

Comment: @BeniBela who removed

Answer (score 2):

This can also be done for flutter.

Add:

```
android{
    buildTypes{
          debug {
              ndk {
                  abiFilters  'arm64-v8a'
              }
          }
    }
}
```

to android\app\build.gradle. That works to remove the x86 libflutter.so libraries from the debug builds and shortens installation time. Works for gradle 7.2