# Android NDK build apk which supports all CPU's architecture

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk

I have written one c file native code for an Android application but when I build the apk and when I want to release that apk, it only supports four CPU's architecture.

Please tell me how to resolve that problem? I want to make the apk which supports all types of CPU architectures.

Comment: All of these: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CPU_architectures? :)

Comment: The only meaningful ABIs to build for are `armeabi-v7a` and `arm64-v8a`. And _maybe_ `x86` and `x86-64`, but the number of x86 Android devices is pretty small, and most of them can run ARM code through emulation. `mips`, `mips64` and `armeabi` are all obsolete/deprecated.

Comment: The number of x86/x86_64 devices is higher than you might think, and frankly the arm emulation is slower and buggier than targeting the ABI directly. Besides, it helps if you can run your code on the emulator.

Answer (score 2):

This should be happening automatically if you're using the canonical build process (i.e. Android Studio with `externalNativeBuild`). If it isn't, update your NDK/SDK/gradle plugin.

If that still doesn't do it, you can try explicitly listing all the ABIs you want to support: [Add abiFilters to gradle properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32487192/632035)

Also note that you really don't want a single APK with libraries for all ABIs, as that would be a very large APK with mostly unused stuff in it. What you really want are [app bundles](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/) which will automatically include only the libraries for the device the user is installing the app too.