# NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null on Android Studio 3.1.2

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

I'm trying to build an Android projects which involves NDK: [CoolMicApp-Android](https://github.com/CoolMicApp/CoolMicApp-Android) (already have the latest Android Studio and NDK installed)

I followed the [BUILDING](https://github.com/CoolMicApp/CoolMicApp-Android/blob/master/BUILDING) note correctly. When the project is loaded in Android Studio, there are some errors:

> Build command failed.
>
> Error while executing
> 'C:\Users\Cipta-NB\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd'
> with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null
> APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\Cipta-NB\StudioProjects\CoolMicApp-Android\app\src\main\jni\Android.mk
> NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\Cipta-NB\StudioProjects\CoolMicApp-Android\app\src\main\jni\Application.mk
> APP_ABI=armeabi NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi NDK_DEBUG=0
> APP_PLATFORM=android-16
> NDK_OUT=C:/Users/Cipta-NB/StudioProjects/CoolMicApp-Android/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/release/obj
> NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\Cipta-NB\StudioProjects\CoolMicApp-Android\app\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\release\lib
> APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}
>
> Android NDK: INTERNAL ERROR: The armeabi ABI should have exactly one
> architecture definitions. Found: ''
>
> process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.
>
> *** Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop. Open File

The C libs can be built successfully by running this command, though:

> ndk-build
> NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\Cipta-NB\StudioProjects\CoolMicApp-Android\app\src\main\jni\Application.mk
> NDK_PROJECT_PATH=C:\Users\Cipta-NB\StudioProjects\CoolMicApp-Android\app\src\main

In my laptop, ndk-build is located in **C:\Users\Cipta-NB\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle**. Creating an environment variable called **NDK_PROJECT_PATH** and restarting Android Studio doesn't solve the problem.

This is the content of local.propertes file in the project directory:

> ndk.dir=C:\Users\Cipta-NB\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle
>
> sdk.dir=C:\Users\Cipta-NB\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

And this is the content of Application.mk

> APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
>
> APP_PLATFORM := android-14

Is there any (easy) workaround?

Comment: Which exact version of the NDK are you using? The latest version (r17) no longer supports armeabi as a target. Build for armeabi-v7a and/or arm64-v8a instead.

Comment: NDK version: v17.0.4754217 (provided by SDK Manager). BTW, I just updated my question a bit. My build target s armeabi-v7a.

Comment: Try adding `abiFilters` in your **build.gradle** since you're only building for one abi.

Comment: Hmm... I modified my gradle.properties and build.gradle (based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32487192/add-abifilters-to-gradle-properties). Well still the same error.

Comment: You don't need to modify gradle.properties, just put `ndk{abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'}` inside `defaultConfig` in build.gradle as described [here](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.NdkOptions.html). From your output it is clear that gradle overrides `APP_ABI` and sets it to `armeabi` which is deprecated as pointed out by Michael.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. `NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null` is a red herring. It only looks alarming. It's not an error. This is how NDK build is configured in Android Studio.
2. The latest NDK r17 dropped support for some ABIs. Unfortunately, the old Gradle plugin does not know that. You can resolve this inconsistency by [tuning your **build.gradle** script](https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/700#issuecomment-392935541), but [upgrading the plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50345736/192373) is easier and safer.

Comment: Thank you. Upgrading Gradle to latest version solves this issue :)

Comment: Would you kindly rename the question to avoid confusion, maybe to *"NDK error with armeabi in Android Studio 3.1.2"* or similar.

Comment: @anta40 which version did you use? The gradle version of 3.1.3 still gives error.

Comment: @Eswar you found any solution?

Comment: @MuhammadHassaan I got it solved but It was some time back. If I remember it right, basically upgrading the packages solved most of the problems. However, there was some minor issues with the abiFilters and the Application.mk

Comment: @Eswar ok no problem , I am working on ndk and getting this error and not able to solve it

Comment: @MuhammadHassaan have you solved it? I get same error here

Comment: @moustaf-el-saghier yes i solved it but i compiled my native code with Cmake instead of Ndk Build