# Android NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

I am working on OpenCV with Android. And I tried run Face detection sample. But I always get same error please help.

> Build command failed. Error while executing process
>   C:\Users\Cevdet\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd
>   with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null
>   APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\Cevdet\AndroidStudioProjects\face-detection\openCVSamplefacedetection\src\main\jni\Android.mk
>   NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\Cevdet\AndroidStudioProjects\face-detection\openCVSamplefacedetection\src\main\jni\Application.mk
>   APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi-v7a NDK_DEBUG=1
>   APP_PLATFORM=android-16
>   NDK_OUT=C:/Users/Cevdet/AndroidStudioProjects/face-detection/openCVSamplefacedetection/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj
>   NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\Cevdet\AndroidStudioProjects\face-detection\openCVSamplefacedetection\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\debug\lib
>   C:/Users/Cevdet/AndroidStudioProjects/face-detection/openCVSamplefacedetection/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libdetection_based_tracker.so}
>   [armeabi-v7a] SharedLibrary  : libdetection_based_tracker.so
>   C:/Users/Cevdet/AndroidStudioProjects/face-detection/openCVSamplefacedetection/src/main/jni/DetectionBasedTracker_jni.cpp:34:
>   error: undefined reference to
>   'DetectionBasedTracker::DetectionBasedTracker(std::__ndk1::basic_string, std::__ndk1::allocator > const&,
>   DetectionBasedTracker::Parameters const&)' clang++.exe: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) make: ***
>   [C:/Users/Cevdet/AndroidStudioProjects/face-detection/openCVSamplefacedetection/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libdetection_based_tracker.so]
>   Error 1

Comment: The error is not `NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50707270/1524450)), it's `undefined reference to 'DetectionBasedTracker::DetectionBasedTracker(std::__ndk1::basic_string, std::__ndk1::allocator > const&, DetectionBasedTracker::Parameters const&)' `

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup OpenCV librairies for your project.

You can follow the instruction here-->https://stackoverflow.com/a/22427267/5773037

Comment: Thanks for reply. I followed the instruction but I got different error. Like this ;

Unable to resolve dependency for ':openCVSamplefacedetection@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :libraries:opencv.

Comment: @Cevdet check your internet connectivity may b it ll be affect

Comment: It's not about Internet.  I clicked the "Make project " button. This is new error .s

"Unable to find a matching configuration of project :libraries:opencv: None of the consumable configurations have attributes."