# force build a flutter application for ARMv7 only

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, flutter, arm

My project is a flutter application as frontend of an Android Service that I import as an AAR.

That Android Service is mostly C++ and only packs ARMV7 libraries. No ARM64.

- If I run the project in Android studio, the debug APK uploaded only contains Flutter ARM64 library, but no `ARM` libraries (from the service), so the service fails to start (the Flutter part works OK).
- If I run the project via terminal with 
  `flutter build apk --debug --target-platform=android-arm`, the resulting APK contains flutter ARM library with the rest of the service ARM libraries. **it works.**

So my question is, how can I append parameter `--target-platform=android-arm` to the flutter build triggered from Android Studio, so I don't need to manually create and upload the APK.

I have tried [Add abiFilters to gradle properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32487192/add-abifilters-to-gradle-properties) but it doesn't seem related.

Answer (score 3):

The project property `target-platform` can be defined on the main `build.gradle`, to add a property to the subprojects. This variable is parsed by `flutter.gradle` to pack the desired architecture. A comma-separated list of platforms can be provided as well.

```
subprojects {
    project.setProperty("target-platform", "android-arm")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this [workaround](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13977#issuecomment-553763510)

In short - modify $flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle
(return PLATFORM_ARM32 from getBasePlatform method) and add ndk.abiFilters to defaultConfig

[Issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/29710) on github.

Comment: ey, thanks for answering. I was indeed going your route when I discovered in the flutter.gradle source code that it checks for a project variable to override platform value. Seems a workaround for the issue without the need of editing flutter.gradle! See my own answer. (btw- flutter.gradle is re-downloaded from github by the flutter toolchain quite frequently, so editions do not survive very long)